# Filter json with select box option value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i filter the "Make" values according to the year. For eg: When i select "Year" as "2012"  the related data i.e; only "def" should be displayed in the drop down box.
Another problem is the previous data in the table was shown again when i select next values.
See the demo for better understanding.

I tried this.

```
$.each(g_Vehicle, function(index) {
 var sMake = g_Vehicle[index].Make;
  if($('#DropDown_Year').val())=='2011'){  /* for testing purpose i give year as 2011*/
   if ($.inArray(sMake, g_MakesArray) == -1) {
    g_MakesArray.push(sMake);
        } 
 }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NFXzn/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter a collection/array use the $.grep, to know more about this take a look at the [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-filter-json-data-using-jquery/) article, this will explain more on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter() {
    switch($(this).text()) {
    case "2012":
        //filter logic
        $("#dropdown2").html("<select>....</select><select>...</select>");
        break;
    ....
    }
}

$("#dropdown").change(filter);
```

You can make the second drop box empty when start and fill it with appropriate selects after someone selects year.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [grep](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.grep#arraycallbackinvert) for this

e.g.

```
var newArray = jQuery.grep(g_Vehicle , function(element, index){
  return element.Make == "abc" ; 
});
```